# object creation assembly in cSharp

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object, .net-assembly

```
        A a = new A();
```

012E2FB8  mov         ecx,58812BCh
012E2FBD  call        011C30F4
012E2FC2  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
012E2FC5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h]
012E2FC8  call        012E0D60
012E2FCD  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]
012E2FD0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax

**More specifically, why are there two calls ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first call is setting the type for the object. The second call is setting the object as a New object of the A class.

Comment: can you elaborate on the first part of your answer?

Comment: C# is a strongly typed language. So every object must have a type. So the first call A a;  sets the type of "a" to be of A class. You don't have to set what "a" is at this point. You can then use (a) at a later point in the program as a= New A();   or a = anotherobjectofclassa;  and then later set a= New A(); which will then set a to a new object. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Also look at inheritance.